# Run powershell script as a local Admin. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell

I'm trying to run this Powershell script as a local admin (`$credential` has PSShellAdmin rights too):

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(".\test",$securePassword)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RM-SERVER -ScriptBlock {Get-Process} -Credential $credential
```

And it says next:

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
 WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Kerb
eros authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service
the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specifie
d.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does
not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no tru
st between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM
TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command:
winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting H
elp topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

I'v tried to solve this problem running the command in PS -> `Enable-PSRemoting`. but it didn't help me. So, what can I do with this error?

Comment: Need more environmental information: what OS is source/target computer? Are there firewalls intervening? Did you run `Enable-PSRemoting` on source and target computers?

Comment: OS - Win7. Locally firewall is disabled (just for time of this test). I did run it locally. How could I test it on the local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a local account to make a network connection ".\test".

Comment: Can you tell me how it really works? I'm trying to test this script locally but it doesn't work. As an example "localhost\test"?                         So I ran the command New-PSSession and the script works locally, but on the server has an error. Is it a good decision to make a new session?

Comment: The `Invoke-Command` command will automatically create and destroy the Remoting session. You don't have to do this manually, unless you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this will help someone who is doing something similar, but in C# code.

Opening a runspace using PSCredential without "\" preceding the username seems to force Kerberos AuthenticationMechansim in workgroup environment if your code is running as localSystem (as in a Window Service case).

```
var username = "foobar";
var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, hostname, Port, AppName, ShellUri,
                new PSCredential(username, password))
            {
                AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate
            };

using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(host, connectionInfo))
{
    runspace.Open(); //will try to negotiate with Kerberos
}
```

fix is to add "\" in front of username to force NTLM on non-domain environment

```
var username = "foobar";
var domain = "";
var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, hostname, Port, AppName, ShellUri,
                new PSCredential(domain + "\\" + username, password))
            {
                AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate
            };

using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(host, connectionInfo))
{
    runspace.Open(); //will try to negotiate with Kerberos in domain, NTLM in non-domain
}
```